# 古い（Firebase でない方の）GoogleCloudMessageは新規プロジェクトで使えるか

Tags: gcm, firebase

GoogleCloudPlatformのAPI managerでGoogleCloudMessagingを選択すると
「Firebase Cloud Messaging」に移動し、そちらを使わせようとするのですが
monacaでの解説ページはまだGCMの時代のもので、そのGCMでのAPIを有効にしたいのですが
そちらはもう使えないようになってしまったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

新しいアプリケーションはFirebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)でスタートせよ、既存のユーザにも移行を推奨する、との事です。

> If you are integrating messaging in a new app, start with FCM.
>   GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.
>   https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm

この書き方からすると、新しくGCMを使い始める事は出来なそうですね。